# json populating only one row in listview in android

Tags: android, json

I have a php file that is return the following to android in a json format :

```
[
   {
      "IDpost":"1",
      "username":"you",
      "FirstN":"Mounzer",
      "LastN":"Yaghi",
      "Content":"test1",
      "Type":"CARS",
      "Dateofp":"2013-03-03"
   },
   {
      "IDpost":"2",
      "username":"boss",
      "FirstN":"Marwan",
      "LastN":"Geha",
      "Content":"test2",
      "Type":"CARS",
      "Dateofp":"2013-03-05"
   },
   {
      "IDpost":"4",
      "username":"boss",
      "FirstN":"Marwan",
      "LastN":"Geha",
      "Content":"hello this is getting boring",
      "Type":"CARS",
      "Dateofp":"2000-02-02"
   }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to populate a listview in some of those informations , but it's not working because of some json exception , here is my java code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Posts extends Activity {
    String type, firstname, lastname, email, number, username, content; 
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addpost);

        Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        type = gotBasket.getString("type_post");
        firstname = gotBasket.getString("fn");
        lastname = gotBasket.getString("ln");
        email = gotBasket.getString("pemail");
        number = gotBasket.getString("number");
        username = gotBasket.getString("user");

        this.setTitle(type);

        Button addp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addpost1);
        addp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                basket.putString("user", username);
                basket.putString("fn", firstname);
                basket.putString("ln", lastname);
                basket.putString("number", number);
                basket.putString("pemail", email);
                basket.putString("type_post", type);

                Intent a = new Intent(Posts.this, Addpost_2.class);
                a.putExtras(basket);
                startActivity(a);       
            }
        });

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

         httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/LTC/Uploadposts.php?type=" + type + "");
         try {
             nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",type));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstN",firstname));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastN",lastname));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content",content));

             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

             if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                 entity = response.getEntity();
                 if (entity != null) {
                     InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                     JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
                     //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),jsonResponse.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                     String retcont = jsonResponse.getString("Content");
                     String getf = jsonResponse.getString("FirstN");
                     String getl = jsonResponse.getString("LastN");
                     String dop = jsonResponse.getString("Dateofp");

                     try {
                         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(convertStreamToString(instream));

                         int jArrayLength = jArray.length();
                         List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(jArrayLength);

                         for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                             JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             listContents.add(json_data.getString("FirstN") + " "
                                         + json_data.getString("LastN") + " "
                                         + json_data.getString("Dateofp")
                                         + "\n\n" +json_data.getString("Content"));
                         }

                         ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                         myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

                     } catch(JSONException e) {
                         Log.e("log_tag","Error parsin data "+e.toString());
                     }
                 }
             }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }
     }

     private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         try {
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
     }
 }
```

I know that the error is in my java code, can anyone help me and tell me what should I change in the code, thank you

Comment: Please 1. format you JSON and 2. post the exception that you get

Comment: value of type org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject, thanks for helping

Comment: Please take the time to format your code as well. Don't just copy-and-paste dump it into the question textbox.

Comment: Guys I'm still learning android, I know that my error is in one or two line but I can't figure it out because I'm new to android. Please If you know what should I change just tell I'll really appreciate that

Comment: @moonwalker try to use my code for getting JSON and tell me if you still have some troubles

Comment: I submitted a code edit for this. This (with some wiggle room) is how you should format the code in future questions. As an aside and for your own good, let me tell you code formatting matters. Your styling was grossly inconsistent. Sometimes you put spaces, sometimes you don't. When you work with people this will lead to lots of pointless git diffs. Also, it just looks ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact exception that you are getting i would guess that you have to replace `new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));` with new `JSONArray(convertStreamToString(instream));` since your PHP returns an array, not an object.

Comment: But that's what I wrote in my code you didn't change anything

Comment: There is a difference: one is a JSONObject, the other is a JSONArray. The Exception you are getting actually tells you what the problem is: jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

```
      public static JSONObject retrieveJsonObjectFromUrl(URL url)
        throws JSONException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        if (url != null) {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {

                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Invalid URL", "Error processing ", e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
}
```